# Control which Bluetooth device get connected to by iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

My iPhone has been paired with my earbuds and my car.  In the list of devices, my earbuds are above my car.  Whenever I turn on my car, however, the audio goes from my earbuds to the car.  In order to avoid this, I don't want to disable BT on my car because when I *do* want the iPhone's audio to go to the car, it's inconvenient to re-enable it and wait for the connection.

How does the iPhone decide which BT device to connect to?  I would have thought that the list would serve as a ranking, with the top device being most preferred (if it is present).  Though the problem with that hypothesis, however, is that there doesn't seem to be a way for the user to choose where a device sits in the list.  So it could very well be wrong, in which case I can see no obvious scheme for deciding which device gets connected to.

I can manually disconnect the car, but when I'm running around doing errands, I have to do this every time I jump in the car.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a few days, it is clear that this is a long standing problem for which there is no solution (as of 2023-12-19).